# Epsilon-Delta of a cubic function

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I have the cubic function $$ \lim_{x \to -2}(x^3+4x^2+4x-1)=-1 $$
which I manage to break down into
$$x(x+2)^2 < \epsilon.$$

How do I proceed with this?
I try to define $x$ by setting $\delta < 1$
but get negative outputs which I frankly do not know what to do with.

Comment: That's *cubic*, not "quadric".

Comment: you are right, i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we want from $|x-(-2)|=|x+2|<\delta$ conclude $|x(x+2)^2|<\varepsilon$ and problem seems to estimate $|x|$, as for $|x+2|$ estimation is clear.

Obviously $|x+2|<\delta \Leftrightarrow 2-\delta<x<2+\delta$, so taking $\delta<1$ gives $1<|x| =x < 3$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow -2} (x^3 +4x^2 +4x -1)=-1\\
\iff |(x^3 +4x^2 +4x -1)-(-1)| = |x^3 +4x^2 +4x| = |x(x^2 +4x +4)| = |x(x+2)^2| \leq |x||x+2|^2 < \varepsilon \\
\Longleftarrow (|x| < \delta_0\ \wedge\ |x+2|^2 < (\varepsilon/\delta_0) = \delta_1^2)\\ 
$$
where $\delta_0$ is any positive number, no matter how *large*. The last conjunct can be written
$$
|x+2| <  \delta_1 = \sqrt{\varepsilon/\delta_0}
$$
Taking $\delta_0$ to be the small one implies that the function has the same limit at $x=0$.